# Dataframe - column don't exist create one

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

lets say we have.

df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[44,66,77]})
print(df)

the dataframe I get from API request

but I am expecting col C , D and E

---- since they are not there I want to add columns C,D and E with empty string values
----but first I should check if these columns dont exist

Comment: [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

A straight forward `dict` comprehension using `**kwargs` to `assign()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3]})
wanted = {"A":20,"B":"a value","C":np.nan}
df = df.assign(**{c:v for c,v in wanted.items() if c not in df.columns})
```

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a value | nan |
| 1 | 2 | a value | nan |
| 2 | 3 | a value | nan |

Comment: lets say we have.      df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3],"B":[44,66,77]})
print(df)              but I am expecting col C , D and E ---- since they are not there I want to add columns C,D and E with null values----but first I should check if these columns dont exist

Comment: then you set `wanted={"C":np.nan,"D":np.nan,"E",np.nan}` and it will add these columns if they don't exist.  Take a look ate the dict comprehension,  it's checking if column already exists in the DF.  You set your requirement in abstract terms - the dict is this abstraction - coding 101